# How to implement this 2 function in one?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create an array with the data coming from a big array that contain 5 arrays inside. 
The problem is that my function repeats 5 times as i need to do a random function for each array to get 2 itema from each and then concat to create the final 10 items array.

This is the big array, it has another 3 arrays inside:

```
var question = [
   CP = [
      { questionNumber: "1", type: "CP", question: "paski?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "2", type: "CP", question: "pepino?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "3", type: "CP", question: "cabron?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "4", type: "CP", question: "ostia?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "5", type: "CP", question: "adios.", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ],
    NP = [
      { questionNumber: "6", type: "NP", question: "quien es mas wapo?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "7", type: "NP", question: "te gusta viajar?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "8", type: "NP", question: "eres romantico?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "9", type: "NP", question: "que te gusta mas?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "10", type: "NP", question: "eres mas...", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ]];
```

and this are the 2 functions:

```
var CPselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    rand();
}
function rand(){
    var ran = CP[Math.floor(Math.random() * CP.length)];  
    if (CPselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        CPselected.push(ran);
    else
         rand();
}



var NPselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    NPrand();
}
function NPrand(){
    var ran = NP[Math.floor(Math.random() * NP.length)];  
    if (NPselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        NPselected.push(ran);
    else
         NPrand();
}
```

And finally i concat:

```
var Selected = CPselected.concat(NPselected);
```

Comment: `var question = [
   CP = [` is invalid syntax. Please post a valid data structure.

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand why is not correct, can i have your help please? As to me work like that code. I make a mistake, is a JSON file.     @CertainPerformance

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have been able to run the code, am I missing the error?

Comment: Is not a code error, is the way to make that 2 function into 1 so i dont repeat the same function 5 times. thanks @OliverRadini

Comment: @Jacofki ok, so you'd like to get a single array, which is a random sorted version of the first two?

Comment: yes @OliverRadini

Answer (score 1):

To address the comments you've received regarding the syntax you've used for the declaration of `question`. Normally in javascript we define objects like this:

```
{
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: 'hello, world],
}
```

In your question you have something more like:

```
[
  a = [1, 2, 3],
  b = 'hello, world',
]
```

This creates an array, rather than an object, and it only works and has the data you want because in javascript, the assignment operation returns the right-hand side of the assignment, for instance:

```
a = 'hello, world'
```

Returns 'hello, world'.

What you have *is* valid syntax, but it's very unusual.

---

Returning to your actual question.

This should hopefully do what you need. The code merges all `question` items into a single array, then transfers a random item to a new list, until there are no items left in the original list.

```js
var question = [
   CP = [
      { questionNumber: "1", type: "CP", question: "paski?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "2", type: "CP", question: "pepino?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "3", type: "CP", question: "cabron?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "4", type: "CP", question: "ostia?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "5", type: "CP", question: "adios.", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ],
    NP = [
      { questionNumber: "6", type: "NP", question: "quien es mas wapo?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "7", type: "NP", question: "te gusta viajar?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "8", type: "NP", question: "eres romantico?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "9", type: "NP", question: "que te gusta mas?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "10", type: "NP", question: "eres mas...", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ]];

const getRandomIndex = list => Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)
const removeArrayItemAtIndex = (list, index) => [
   ...list.slice(0, index),
   ...list.slice(index + 1, list.length),
];

const randomSortTick = (listA, listB) => {
  const indexToTransfer = getRandomIndex(listA);
  return [
     removeArrayItemAtIndex(listA, indexToTransfer),
     [
       ...listB,
       listA[indexToTransfer],
     ],
  ]
}

const transferArrays = (listA, listB, transferFunction) =>
  listA.length > 0 ?
    transferArrays(...transferFunction(listA, listB), transferFunction) :
    [listA, listB]
    
const randomlySortQuestions = questions =>
  transferArrays(
    [...questions[0], ...questions[1]],
    [],
    randomSortTick
  )[1]

console.dir(
  randomlySortQuestions(question)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First of all, the `question` array you have shown isn't valid JavaScript syntax and therefor leads to a `SyntaxError`.</strike> **EDIT**: *That's not true. It does work.*

However, since your question is more about merging both function into one:

Look at the functions you already have and determine what differentiates them from another. For a better overview:

```
function rand(){
  var ran = CP[Math.floor(Math.random() * CP.length)];  
  if (CPselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
    CPselected.push(ran);
  else
    rand();
}

// ... Left out for brevity ...

function NPrand(){
  var ran = NP[Math.floor(Math.random() * NP.length)];  
  if (NPselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
    NPselected.push(ran);
  else
    NPrand();
}
```

Both of them do *exactly the same* (calculating a random `Number`, select one element from an already existing `Array` based on that number and push the element into a new `Array`). They only *differ* in which `Array` is used as a "source" and which is used as a "destination". This means you can easily create a single function from both of them, by passing the "source" and "destination" arrays *as parameters/arguments to the function*:

```
function selectRandom (sourceArray, destinationArray) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceArray.length);
  if (destinationArray.indexOf(sourceArray[randomIndex]) < 0) {
    destinationArray.push(sourceArray[randomIndex]);
  } else {
    selectRandom(sourceArray, destinationArray);
  }
}
```

This can replace both functions you currently have (`rand` as well as `NPrand`). All you have to remember is to pass in the right source and destination array.

Are we finished now? In short: No. We can abstract that code even further! Let's have a look at the two *loops*:

```
var CPselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  rand();
}

// ... Left out for brevity ...

var NPselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  NPrand();
}
```

Guess what: They do *exactly the same as well*, so let's also abstract them away. Combined with the `selectRandom` function, we arrive at:

```
function randomSelect2 (sourceArray) {
  var destinationArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    selectRandom(sourceArray, destinationArray);
  }
  return destinationArray;
}
```

Check it out:

```js
function selectRandom (sourceArray, destinationArray) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceArray.length);
  if (destinationArray.indexOf(sourceArray[randomIndex]) < 0) {
    destinationArray.push(sourceArray[randomIndex]);
  } else {
    selectRandom(sourceArray, destinationArray);
  }
}

function randomSelect2 (sourceArray) {
  var destinationArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    selectRandom(sourceArray, destinationArray);
  }
  return destinationArray;
}



console.log(randomSelect2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(randomSelect2(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
```

**TL;DR**

Not enough yet? We can merge what we have now *into a single function*. The `selectRandom` function already uses *recursion*, if the random element from the source array already exists inside the destination array, right? By passing in another argument which tells the maximum amount of items we want to select from the source array, we can then write a *recursive* function that wraps *all the things into a single function*:

```js
function randomSelect (count, sourceArray, destinationArray) {
  if (destinationArray.length >= count) {
    // the "base case", used to break out of recursion
    return destinationArray;
  }

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceArray.length);
  var item = sourceArray[randomIndex];
  if (destinationArray.indexOf(item) < 0) {
    // call "randomSelect" again with the item added to the destination (recurse)
    return randomSelect(count, sourceArray, destinationArray.concat(item));
  }
  // call "randomSelect" again (recurse)
  return randomSelect(count, sourceArray, destinationArray);
}

console.log(randomSelect(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], []));
console.log(randomSelect(2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], []));
```

Awesome. It has a severe drawback though which isn't obvious: As of now, this function *isn't stack safe*, meaning that large numbers (first argument) *possibly blow the stack*. To fix that, you can use *trampolines*. However, it isn't necessary to use the recursive definition. If you want to go down that rabbit hole, have a look [here](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/28/trampolines-in-javascript.html).

Comment: Could you explain why `question` isn't valid javascript syntax? It works for me

Comment: @OliverRadini Sorry, you are right. It _does work_. Fixed my answer.

Comment: I think you'd be right to mention that it is indeed very odd syntax, I would not have realised that it was valid unless I just lazily copied it to my own answer!

Comment: Also, I don't think this is a new addition with es6 destructuring; it's just a standard array, the assignment statements will be evaluated, and return their right hand side, so it's just like having the arrays in the array. I'm sure that isn't what the OP originally intended (they probably wanted a standard object), and it's very bizarre,  but it should work as is on older browsers

Answer (score -2):

```js
function randomSelect (count, sourceArray, destinationArray) {
  if (destinationArray.length >= count) {
    // the "base case", used to break out of recursion
    return destinationArray;
  }

  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceArray.length);
  var item = sourceArray[randomIndex];
  if (destinationArray.indexOf(item) < 0) {
    // call "randomSelect" again with the item added to the destination (recurse)
    return randomSelect(count, sourceArray, destinationArray.concat(item));
  }
  // call "randomSelect" again (recurse)
  return randomSelect(count, sourceArray, destinationArray);
}

console.log(randomSelect(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], []));
console.log(randomSelect(2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], []));
```

Thanks for the details answer but i think it doesnt get what i what, i will write all my code so can see.
In the array there are 25 items in 5 groups.

```
var question = [
   CP = [
      { questionNumber: "1", type: "CP", question: "paski?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "2", type: "CP", question: "pepino?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "3", type: "CP", question: "cabron?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "4", type: "CP", question: "ostia?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "5", type: "CP", question: "adios.", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ],
    NP = [
      { questionNumber: "6", type: "NP", question: "quien es mas wapo?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "7", type: "NP", question: "te gusta viajar?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "8", type: "NP", question: "eres romantico?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "9", type: "NP", question: "que te gusta mas?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "10", type: "NP", question: "eres mas...", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ],
   A = [
      { questionNumber: "11", type: "A", question: "paski?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "12", type: "A", question: "pepino?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "13", type: "A", question: "cabron?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "14", type: "A", question: "ostia?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "15", type: "A", question: "adios.", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ],
   FC = [
      { questionNumber: "16", type: "FC", question: "paski?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "17", type: "FC", question: "pepino?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "18", type: "FC", question: "cabron?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "19", type: "FC", question: "ostia?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "20", type: "FC", question: "adios.", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ],
   AC = [
      { questionNumber: "21", type: "AC", question: "paski?", answer1: "yo", answer2:"javier"},
      { questionNumber: "22", type: "AC", question: "pepino?", answer1: "si", answer2:"no"},
      { questionNumber: "23", type: "AC", question: "cabron?", answer1: "si", answer2:"a veces"},
      { questionNumber: "24", type: "AC", question: "ostia?", answer1: "carne", answer2:"pescado"},
      { questionNumber: "25", type: "AC", question: "adios.", answer1: "dormilon", answer2:"hablador"}
   ]
];
```

so here i have 5 times the functions to get 2 random items from each group.

```
var CPselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    rand();
}
function rand(){
    var ran = CP[Math.floor(Math.random() * CP.length)];  
    if (CPselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        CPselected.push(ran);
    else
         rand();
}

var NPselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    NPrand();
}
function NPrand(){
    var ran = NP[Math.floor(Math.random() * NP.length)];  
    if (NPselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        NPselected.push(ran);
    else
         NPrand();
}

var Aselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    Arand();
}
function Arand(){
    var ran = A[Math.floor(Math.random() * A.length)];  
    if (Aselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        Aselected.push(ran);
    else
         Arand();
}

var FCselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    FCrand();
}
function FCrand(){
    var ran = FC[Math.floor(Math.random() * FC.length)];  
    if (FCselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        FCselected.push(ran);
    else
         FCrand();
}

var ACselected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    ACrand();
}
function ACrand(){
    var ran = AC[Math.floor(Math.random() * AC.length)];  
    if (ACselected.indexOf(ran) == -1)
        ACselected.push(ran);
    else
         ACrand();
}
```

Here i concat the 5 arrays into one

```
var Selected = CPselected.concat(NPselected, Aselected, FCselected, ACselected);
```

And here i show it in html

```
document.getElementById("data_area").innerHTML = 
"<div id='question_1' class='question_data'><div class='no'>" +CPselected[0].questionNumber+ "</div><div class='type'>" +CPselected[0].type+ "</div><div class='question'>" + CPselected[0].question + "</div><div class='answer_1'>" + CPselected[0].answer1 + "</div><div class='answer_2'>" + CPselected[0].answer2 + "</div></div><div id='question_2' class='question_data'><div class='no'>" +CPselected[1].questionNumber+ "</div><div class='type'>" +CPselected[1].type+ "</div><div class='question'>" + CPselected[1].question + "</div><div class='answer_1'>" + CPselected[1].answer1 + "</div><div class='answer_2'>" + CPselected[1].answer2 + "</div></div>";
```

Comment: In future it'd be good to try and show some example output of what you want, you have three fairly long winded answers here and none of them produce the same output, which would indicate that your question could perhaps have been clearer

Comment: @Jacofki Indeed, my answer _doesn't_ produce the final output. What it does, is to explain you _how to get rid of 5 times the same loop and 5 times the same function_. That's what you asked for (in regards to the title and your own comments).

Comment: Thanks OliverRadini and David, after i nice sleep i got the answer.